# Does FileWriter when appending simply copy and rewrite a file or does it physically append text to the specified file-java

Tags: java

(java 8)So to know efficiency wise I was wondering if within it's class filewriter handles append by manually reading the old file and overwriting it with the old text contents plus what you want to append(like you would if appending with filewriter wasn't an option).

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
```

If I were to use append like above would it be faster to append like this or manually basically?

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-): *"If the second argument is true, then **bytes will be written to the end of the file** rather than the beginning."* Which part of this makes you think it copies the existing data in the file?

Comment: @Andreas Yea, you're right it doesn't imply that it gets copied I saw that but was being tripped up by "rather than the beginning" as I thought that implied FileWriter prepends by default rather than overwriting which is not true . Any idea for the efficiency I would assume based on this append is much faster, but I can't be sure. Thanks for the help